# Facebook Access Token [Javascript SDK]

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am writing Facebook login for my site.I am using Javascript Sdk,but I don't understand one thing.

```
  function fbLogin() {
   FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
    var token=response.authResponse.accessToken;
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {

       $.get('main/check_facebook_status/'+token,function(data) {
            if (data == "true") {
                $('#r_name').val(response.name);
                $('#r_username').val(response.username);
                $('#r_email').val(response.email);
                $('#fbid').val(response.id);
                $('#fbtoken').val(token);


            }
       })
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email, publish_stream'});
  }
```

Can I trust he access token(response.authResponse.accessToken) for identify the user ? Can facebook change the access token ? If changes the access token how can I identify the user ?

Ps:Sorry for bad english

Comment: It looks like you’re making a server-side call here to get details from the API – so why are you doing the same thing client-side before?

Comment: You don’t use the access token to identify the user – you use it to get _information_ about them that identifies them.

Comment: Which information will identify the user ? Facebook id can pass,I can't use for security reason.

Comment: Well then look the id up server-side with the access token you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Can I trust he access token(response.authResponse.accessToken) for identify the user?**

Of-course yes!

> **Can Facebook change the access token ?**

Nope. But it expires after 2 hours, so you have to get the token again. If you want to use this token in future; you can extend the life of the token to 60 days.

You can read more about access tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

---

**[Edit]**

The token also becomes invalidated in the following cases-

- User changes the password
- User de-authorizes the app
- User removes the app

Comment: If user try to login 61th day ?

Comment: then you can not use that token. You have to refresh the token by repeating the process (mentioned in the link in the answer)

Comment: Thank you :) I am getting user id from access token in php sdk :)

Comment: Facebook CAN change the token, if the user deauthorizes the app.